# OAuth Authentication with Twitter API failed!

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

I used R's packages 'twitteR' and 'ROAuth' to access Twitter API.
I tried this R code to register my R session:

```
tw<-OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey="mykeyhere",consumerSecret="mysecrethere",  
requestURL="http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
accessURL="http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
authURL="http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize")
tw<-handshake()
```

I used http instead of https because the latter gave me an error of SSL certification fail.
Then, I enter a PIN code obtained from a given URL and registered with Twitter:

```
registerTwitterOAuth(tw)
```

The result of the above command was:

```
[1] TRUE
```

I think that I successfully registered using OAuth.
However, when I tried to access protected users' profiles, for example,

```
getURL("http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&user_id=XXXXXXXX")
```

I got this:

```
[1] "{\"error\":\"Not authorized\",\"request\":\"\\/1\\/followers\\/ids.json?cursor=-1&user_id=XXXXXXXX\"}"
```

I also checked my verification by using:

```
getURL("http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json")
```

And this was the result:

```
[1] "{\"error\":\"Could not authenticate you.\",\"request\":\"\\/1\\/account\\/verify_credentials.json\"}"
```

Would you mind helping me please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try to make a post to your twitter account using this?  If so what was the result?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `getUser(...)`,`searchTwitter(...)`,`tw$OAuthRequest(...)` and so on instead of directly use `getURL(...)` by yourself because `getURL()` does not contain session context (which register using `registerTwitterOAuth`).

[example of tw$OAuthRequest http://goo.gl/6IwdU](http://goo.gl/6IwdU)