# Streaming package R

Tags: r, stream, aggregate

I'm trying to find R package that helps with aggregating data from stream of data(another program is updating txt file). 
To be more specific(example): only reading data on change and calculating mean of last 4 instances. 
Do you know package that supports this kind of thing?
Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for something like using `repeat` function with condition on _system time_ to schedule a process periodically ?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10070476/6779509