# twitter followers connectedness R Python

Tags: r, twitter, igraph, sna

I'm trying to get an adjacency matrix of the followers of an institution in Twitter with the connections between them. I want to see how do the followers relate to each other. I know what to do from the adjacency matrix on, `igraph` and `statnet` packages allow that. But I'm having troubles getting the matrix.

I've tried working with `twitteR` package to get the users one by one but I get timeout or the machine hangs. I haven't seen this done, but I'm sure there's a shorter way. Any insights or references on this matter would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried calling twitter API directly through `RCurl`?

Comment: here's the loop I used to get follower data for a batch of users from Twitter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9950670/1036500