# Remove chararcters in text corpus

Tags: regex, r, text-mining, tm

I'm analyzing a corpus of emails. Some emails contain URLs. When I apply the `removePunctuation` function from the **tm** library, I get `httpwww`, and then I lose the info of a web address. What I would like to do, is to replace the `"://"` with `" "` across all of the corpus. I tried `gsub`, but then I the datatype of the corpus changes and I can't continue to process it with **tm** package.

Here is an example:

As you can see, `gsub` changes the class of the corpus to an array of characters, causing `tm_map` to fail.

```
> corpus
# A corpus with 4257 text documents
> corpus1 <- gsub("http://","http ",corpus)
> class(corpus1)
# [1] "character"
> class(corpus)
# [1] "VCorpus" "Corpus"  "list"   
> cleanSW <- tm_map(corpus1,removeWords, stopwords("english"))
# Error in UseMethod("tm_map", x) : 
# no applicable method for 'tm_map' applied to an object of class "character"
> cleanSW <- tm_map(corpus,removeWords, stopwords("english"))
> cleanSW
# A corpus with 4257 text documents
```

How can I bypass it? Maybe there's a way to convert it back to corpus from array of characters?

Comment: You can't `paste("://", ...)` back in successfully?

Comment: how do I use it across the whole corpus?

Comment: what about the other `/` and the possible `.` or `:` in the web address?

Comment: Same issue, I just gave the  :// as an example, but as you mentioned it applies to some more characters as well.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried and provide data?

Comment: Hi Tyler, I fixed to question, hope it's more clear now

Comment: You haven't gotten any help because you haven't provided data.  A minimal working example is almost always required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution to this problem here: [Removing non-English text from Corpus in R using tm()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153504/removing-non-english-text-from-corpus-in-r-using-tm), Corpus(VectorSource(dat1)) worked for me.