# How to remove emojis from Tweets in R code

Tags: r, twitter, emoji

Am R newbie.   Am using Mac OSX 10.9.5 and R Studio Version 0.98.1056

Am trying some R script to conduct sentiment analysis on tweets.   When I run the R script i get errors such as the one below as i try to sentiment score some tweets.

Error: invalid input ...followed by the tweet in quotes which always includes ������ at the point the person used an emoji.

I believe the error is caused because the original tweet contains emoji and R is not sure what to do at that point.   I am trying to figure our what R code should be used to remove / ignore emoji as i set up the file for processing.

Any tips or links to how others have solved this are appreciated.

Comment: This may be what you are after. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748190/emoticons-in-twitter-sentiment-analysis-in-r

Comment: Thx jazzuro - perfect link.   I was able to use the iconv function mentioned.