# remove long complex html tags from strings in R

Tags: r, regex, twitter, gsub, data-cleaning

I have already tried and researched the answer to this question on stackoverflow but the solutions do not work for me. 
I am cleaning tweets in R and I have this specific tweet from the list "xALL" that I cannot seem to clean.
I have first collected tweets with "twitteR" about "ai" and put them into a dataframe "AI". The list xALL is the column AI$text.  This is xALL[70] :

```
[1] "My #replika has a cob on with me already <ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082>
#replika #AI #arguingwithrobots https://twitter.com/katieshanks1/status/856102725519626241/photo/1"
```

How can I get rid of these html tags?

The result should look like this:

```
[1] "My #replika has a cob on with me already
#replika #AI #arguingwithrobots https://twitter.com/katieshanks1/status/856102725519626241/photo/1"
```

I have already tried these as suggested in other threads:

```
xALL <- gsub("<.*>", "",xALL)
xALL <- gsub("<(.*)>", "",xALL)
xALL <- gsub("<[^>]+>", "", xALL)
xALL <- gsub("<.*?>", "",xALL)
```

Every time I look at this specific tweet again to verify whether any of the above solutions worked it did not change.

Here are all the commands from the very beginning that I ran for more context:

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_secret)
AItweets <- searchTwitter('#ai',lang="en", n=250)
AI <- twListToDF(AItweets)

AI$text <- as.character(AI$text)

xALL <- AI$text
```

It might be a regex mistake. I have to admit that I am an absolute beginner in this topic. Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: What does `cat(xALL[70])` show? If there are really substrings like `<ed>`, they should be removed with `gsub("<[^>]+>", "", xALL)`

Comment: One of the solution is working for me `gsub("<.*?>", "", str1)`

Comment: What's wrong with `gsub("<.*?>", "", xALL)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 
this is shown: 
`> cat(xALL[70])
My #replika has a cob on with me already <ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082> #replika #AI #arguingwithrobots https://twitter.com/katieshanks1/status/856102725519626241/photo/1`

Comment: See http://ideone.com/E89MYP.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré 
The problem is that this specific tweet is not changed after I run this command.
Here is my output:
`> xALL <- gsub("<.*?>", "", xALL)
> xALL[70]
[1] "My #replika has a cob on with me already <ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082> #replika #AI #arguingwithrobots https://twitter.com/katieshanks1/status/856102725519626241/p‌​hoto/1" `

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it. The problem was that the tweets actually used emoticons which were unreadable to R and they were displayed in these tags. 
So my gsub did not work on them.

This code (of course applied to my context) found in this thread [Emoticons in Twitter Sentiment Analysis in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748190/emoticons-in-twitter-sentiment-analysis-in-r)
solved my problem. It was not a regex problem but I did not recognize it at the time of asking.

```
df$text <- sapply(df$text,function(row) iconv(row, "latin1", "ASCII",
sub=""))
```

After applying this the gsub works as indicated. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score -1):

Your first and third regex work fine.  You should probably post a bit more context.  Maybe you're getting some variables mixed up or something.

Comment: Let's also see how you're applying gsub and checking the output.

Comment: This is how I apply gsub and what output I get.
`> xALL <- gsub("<.*?>", "", xALL)

 > xALL[70] [1] "My #replika has a cob on with me already <ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD>‌​<ed><U+00B8><U+0082>‌​<ed><U+00A0><U+00BD>‌​<ed><U+00B8><U+0082> #replika #AI #arguingwithrobots https://twitter.com/katieshanks1/status/856102725519626241/p‌​‌​hoto/1" `

Comment: Could you include this in your question so that it becomes a minimal example of your problem?  Include some data as well please.