# remove emoticons in R using tm package

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, tm, emoticons

I'm using the tm package to clean up a Twitter Corpus. However, the package is unable to clean up emoticons.

Here's a replicated code:

```
July4th_clean <- tm_map(July4th_clean, content_transformer(tolower))
Error in FUN(content(x), ...) : invalid input 'RT ElleJohnson Love of country is encircling the globes ������������������ july4thweekend July4th FourthOfJuly IndependenceDay NotAvailableOnIn' in 'utf8towcs'
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to remove the emoticons using the tm package?

Thank you,

Luis

Comment: It is not clear from your example  what you wish to eliminate.  Do you want to eliminate substrings that contain multiple consecutive punctuation marks   like :-)  and (-_-)  or are you trying to eliminate odd Unicode characters like ☺ and ❀ ?

Comment: You are right. I assumed that it was a  or something similar.

Comment: I am a R newbie. Do you know how I could check that particular tweet? I imagine you use the [] but not sure if the function or any other part of the code.

Comment: Hi G5W, the emoticon is a peach and a USA flag. 

Comment: I am trying to eliminate odd Unicode characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to get rid of all non-ASCII characters.

```
Texts = c("Let the stormy clouds chase, everyone from the place ☁  ♪ ♬",
    "See you soon brother ☮ ",
    "A boring old-fashioned message" ) 

gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", Texts)
[1] "Let the stormy clouds chase, everyone from the place    "
[2] "See you soon brother  "                                  
[3] "A boring old-fashioned message"
```

**Details:**
You can specify character classes in regex's with `[ ]`.  When the class description starts with `^` it means everything *except* these characters. Here, I have specified everything except characters 1-127, i.e. everything except standard ASCII and I have specified that they should be replaced with the empty string.

Comment: What if you would like to keep characters with accents? For example, é and È.

Comment: @WillM   `gsub("[^\x01-\xFF]", "", Texts)` would leave the simple accented characters.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this function

```
iconv(July4th_clean, "latin1", "ASCII", sub="")
```

Duplicate issue, [see post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748190/emoticons-in-twitter-sentiment-analysis-in-r)

Comment: Hi Zeyad, I did see that one but hesitated using it because the code was different than the tm code I was using. I was using the <- tm_map function.

Comment: you should run this before using the `tm` package

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `rm_non_words` from the `qdapRegex` package, because it allows me to remove emojis and emoticons while keeping characters in different European languages.

e.g.:

```
x1<-"Ελληνικά :), български, français ✅ "
x2<-rm_non_words(x1)
print(x2)
[1]"Ελληνικά български français"
```