# How can I solve this R error message relating to atomic vectors?

Tags: r, gsub, tm

I am using `R` in `RStudio` and I am the running the following codes to perform a sentiment analysis on a set of unstructured texts. 
Since the bunch of texts contain some invalid characters (caused by the use of emoticons and other typo errors), I want to remove them before proceeding with the analysis.

My R codes (extract) stand as follows:

```
setwd("E:/sentiment")

doc1=read.csv("book1.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

# replace specific characters in doc1
  doc1<-gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", doc1)

library(tm)

#Build Corpus
corpus<- iconv(doc1$Review.Text, to = 'utf-8')
corpus<- Corpus(VectorSource(corpus))
```

I get the following error message when I reach this line of code `corpus<- iconv(doc1$Review.Text, to = 'utf-8')`:

```
Error in doc1$Review.Text : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I had a look at the following `StackOverflow` questions:

[remove emoticons in R using tm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893354/remove-emoticons-in-r-using-tm-package)

[Replace specific characters within strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/replace-specific-characters-within-strings)

I have also tried the following to clean my texts before running the tm package, but I am getting the same error: `doc1<-iconv(doc1, "latin1", "ASCII", sub="")`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: with `doc1<-gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", doc1)` you overwrite `doc1`, from this on it is not a dataframe but a character vector. `doc1<-gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", iris); str(doc1)`

Comment: `doc1` is a `data.frame` and I guess that you want to apply `gsub` on the columns of doc1. If you apply `gsub` (which expects a character vector) directly on `doc1`, it gets coerced to a character vector and therefore the error.

Comment: Getting your point. I guess then it should be doc1$Review.Text

Comment: @jogo Thanks. Please elaborate as an answer and I vote accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
doc1<-gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", doc1)
```

you overwrite the object `doc1`, from this on it is not a dataframe but a character vector; see:

```
doc1 <- gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", iris)
str(doc1)
```

and now clear

```
doc1$Species
```

produces the error.
Eventually you want to do:

```
doc1$Review.Text <- gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", doc1$Review.Text)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should run gsub on my target column in the data frame. In this case it is column Review.Text
So my code should look like this:  doc1<-gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", doc1$Review.Text)

Comment: No, also with `doc1 <- ... whatever` you are overwriting your dataframe `doc1`. See my edited answer.