# Finding the PIN from Twitter.Com after using twitteR library on R and ROAuth package

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth, roauth

I have a question that I hope someone could help me with.

I am trying to get some tweets from Twitter via R, using the twitteR library and the other required packages.  I have successfully created my code up to the handshake.  But as soon as I reach the point where I am supposed to copy and paste a link to get the required PIN, I am redirected to the placeholder website address I have registered with Twitter.

Below is my block of code:

```
cred <- OAuthFactory$new (consumerKey = consumerKey, consumerSecret = consumerSecret, requestURL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", accessURL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token", authURL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize")
cred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
```

This then leads to a prompt

```
To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=_______________________
```

I have tried several of the answers in Stackoverflow.Com such as [No PIN generated when using ROAuth to authenticate on Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16057277/2731585), [Where does twitteR PIN code appear during R oauth authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042271/where-does-twitter-pin-code-appear-during-r-oauth-authentication) but no success.

Any response will be really helpful.

Thanks.

BTW: R Noob and basic programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid to be redirected to the placeholder website and see your PIN.

You should :

- go back to your twitter app https://apps.twitter.com/app/
- in the settings, erase the placeholder website address you gave
- save

Next time you will use http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xxxx
and click on "authorize", you will see the PIN.