# twitteR ROAuth handshake error: not generating the PIN option

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth, roauth

This question actually answers all questions related to twitteR ROAuth problems:

[TwitteR, ROAuth and Windows: register OK, but certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916283/twitter-roauth-and-windows-register-ok-but-certificate-verify-failed)

TwitteR and ROAuth both worked perfectly in my pc before. But the code chunk is not generating the PIN option anymore. It pops out the following:

```
twitCred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")
Error: Unauthorized
```

Previously ***twitCred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")*** directs to:

```
To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=SevxcpCh9riO5PPrI8U8____
When complete, record the PIN given to you
```

I tried my code in spark rstudio server. Then the code works perfectly (generating the option to enter the PIN, which is currently not generated in my pc). The code is:

```
require(twitteR)
require(ROAuth)

requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "______________"
consumerSecret <- "___________________"


twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
consumerSecret=consumerSecret, requestURL=requestURL, accessURL=accessURL,
authURL=authURL)


setwd("/home/__")
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")
twitCred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")
  To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
  https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=SevxcpCh9riO5PPrI8U8____
  When complete, record the PIN given to you
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Now twitCred$handshake is working in my pc. I guess twitter developer site block the ip for a limited time because of over-usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
twitCred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Can you add a bit more to this to explain perhaps *why* this worked (e.g. tell the user what they did wrong?)

Comment: Twitter API sometimes block the IP address if one starts to download lots of tweets continuously. Otherwise, this code works perfectly fine if the usage is limited.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary for the Twitter App to have read, write permissions. This is was what made me bypass the authorization errors. Please note the following instructions:

Create a Twitter application at http://dev.twitter.com. Make sure to give the **app read, write and direct message authority.**
Take note of the following values from the Twitter app page: "API key", "API secret", "Access token", and "Access token secret".

install.packages(c("devtools", "rjson", "bit64", "httr"))
Make sure to restart your R session at this point

library(devtools)
install_github("twitteR", username="geoffjentry")
library(twitteR)
setup_twitter_oauth("API key", "API secret")

The API key and API secret are from the Twitter app page above. This will lead you through httr's OAuth authentication process. I recommend you look at the man page for Token in httr for an explanation of how it handles caching.

You should be ready to go!