# How to get R to accept self signed certificates

Tags: r, ssl

I have the following code using the Package RGoogleAnaytics

```
require(RGoogleAnalytics)
client.id <- "XX"
client.secret <- "YY"
token <- Auth(client.id,client.secret)
save(token,file="./token_file")
```

When running this it goes into my browser and asks me to login to my account which has the Google Analytics profiles i wish to access.
Once this has been done R prompts me to return to R and proceed
However in R I get the error:

```
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

How can I rectify this?
Is there a way to force R to accept such certificates?
Is there a way to change the type of certificate that the page gives me?

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916283/twitter-roauth-and-windows-register-ok-but-certificate-verify-failed - and you can always [add them to your local system's cert store](http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml).

Comment: @hrbrmstr I tried the solution suggested, However, the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916283/twitter-roauth-and-windows-register-ok-but-certificate-verify-failed cant be applied to auth. I am unable to perform the same action using Oauth also.

Answer (score 0):

The former solution doesn't work for me with the latest version of `devtools`.
To solve the problem change the `.` for a `_`

```
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
```

I beleive the reason is the the new version of of the package `devtools` changed from `RCurl` to `curl` (or viceversa).

Comment: Without loading `httr`: `httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))`

Answer (score -1):

Found this quick fix

```
set_config( config( ssl.verifypeer = 0L ) )
```

disables certificate verification and hence allows me to proceed.