# Issue ,while deploying the shiny application into my account

Tags: r, shiny

While Deploying my Application into my shinyapps.io ,it showing error as shown below, can anyone suggest me how to solve this issue

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
```

Comment: Please put a re-producible example or see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344357/how-to-get-r-to-accept-self-signed-certificates

Comment: @RahulAgarwal , while publishing application to my shinyapps.io account , it is showing the error and what do you mean by re-producible example

Comment: By re-producible example I mean, paste your code here or a similar code which is giving the same error, so anyone can check at their end and help you. You can also check the link in above comment.

Comment: @MandavaGeethabhargava are you using a corporate network? The firewall or a proxy might be the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am using corporate network what I have to do is there any alternative @Barbara

Comment: @RahulAgarwal code is working well and it is not a problem ,actual my problem is with deployment from  R Studio IDE

Comment: @MandavaGeethabhargava you can try the solutions suggested here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/aRz59VoAFdk but as far as I can see there is no quick solution, you might have to talk with the network administrator.